# PE File sections - SizeOfRawData or VirtualSize

Tags: c, windows, winapi, portable-executable, internals

Lately I've been messing around with PE files at my workplace and became interested in the work of the Windows' loader behind the scenes.
I know that when loading a PE file, the loader needs to copy the PE sections to the allocated PE memory, some loaders commit `SizeOfRawData` bytes, some commit `VirtualSize` bytes for the section and sometimes `SectionAlignment` (When SizeOfRawData equals 0, for uninitialized data).
My question is how can I know that `SectionAlignment` bytes will be enough for all the section's uninitialized data? maybe I have an uninitialized buffer that is much bigger than `SectionAlignment`, so how can I be sure that it won't override other sections? and I can I predict the size needed to be allocated? Can I commit `VirtualSize` bytes instead of `SectionAlignment` bytes to be safe?

Comment: What do you mean by "some loaders" ?  Different versions of Windows?  Third-party loaders?  The loader for boot drivers vs. the loader for applications?

Comment: Then it's possible that they're just doing it wrong.  I think the specification requires you to allocate `VirtualSize` bytes for each section.

Comment: But what should you do when SizeOfRawData is bigger than VirtualSize (which is not unusual)? You are at risk to get an exception when copying the section contents into the allocated memory.The solution I found is: 1) do `max` between VirtualSize and SizeOfRawData, aka `dwAllocationSize`. 2) Allocate dwAllocationSize bytes and set memory to zero. 3) Copy SizeOfRawData bytes from PointerToRawData into the allocated area. These rules seem to work fine for me (at least until I'll find that I did something wrong. For now, all the loaders I've explored had some bugs and inconsistencies in that area)

Comment: That's very odd; have you been able to identify the circumstances under which SizeOfRawData is bigger than VirtualSize?  (For example, do the Microsoft build tools ever do this, or is it just that some third-party build tools are broken?)  FWIW I think your solution is the only sensible one, though perhaps you should see what the Windows loader does.  (The other option being to truncate the data, I suppose.)

Comment: Just compiled a Test DLL with VS, here is a screenshot taken from CFF explorer. At the left, VirtualSize, at the right, SizeOfRawData. http://imgur.com/dwRoUbm. Just implemented a quick basic loader, my solution works. still, I don't know if it is the right solution and I'm too tired to reverse the loader so I guess I should deal with the uncertainty.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what's happening.  The extra bytes are just padding, for alignment within the PE file.  In principle, you should probably truncate them.  On the other hand, if you were using file mappings (as the Windows loader presumably does) then I think the page alignment means that the padding would get loaded into memory, and some DLLs generated by third-party tools might depend on that undocumented behaviour.  So I think the algorithm you're using is probably the safest choice.

Comment: Similar reasoning might explain why some loaders take SectionAlignment into consideration when allocating address space.  The section after the one you're loading must be aligned to a multiple of SectionAlignment, and one way to ensure this would be to round the allocation up accordingly.  (It should be rounded up, though; I'm sure that it would be wrong to allocate less than VirtualSize.)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.The compiler sets `VirtualSize` to contain the raw data + the uninitialized data of the section when loaded into the memory.However, the compiler aligns the `SizeOfRawData` using `SectionAlignment` and thats why it is sometimes bigger than the `VirtualSize`. However, to stay on the safe side (means allocation enough space for raw data and uninitialized data) one should use my solution because it can be *crucial* when taking into consideration the VirtualProtect that comes right after loading the section,would you take the risk of protecting only part of the section?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  One nitpick: `SizeOfRawData` should be aligned to `FileAlignment` rather than `SectionAlignment`.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand it, the Windows loader does not generally `copy the PE sections to the allocated PE memory`. Rather, it creates a file mapping for each relevant section of the PE, each with its virtual size, and then lets the paging system bring the file content into committed memory as needed.

Section alignment normally refers to the minimum section resolution size, typically 4096 bytes (the size of a traditional memory page).

Size of raw data is the size of the data actually present in the PE image on disk for the section.

Comment: You are correct. this is exactly how the windows loader does that, and it is easy because you have a file on disk. When loading a DLL from buffer it can't be done that way and therefore the sections should get copied from the buffer to the allocated memory and get committed right after. Look at my last comment the question, maybe you could assist me resolving this issue.